# Multiple buttons for same function with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, switch-statement, case

I've tried to make my own case function, but I cannot get it to "show stuff" once I've hidden them on first click. So my question is what am I doing wrong, how can I solve it, and how should I've done it instead?

My only requirement is that multiple buttons can use the same code to show/hide the same object – hence things like `oddClick` won't work since that'll require unnecessary clicks to get even/odd again (I think?).

```
        $('.boxbtn').on('click', function () {
        var boxwidth = $('.box').width();
        console.log(boxwidth);
        console.log('-'+boxwidth+'px');
        var state = 1;

        if(state == 0) {  // I think we are trying to compare value here.
/*              alert("foo"); */
            var state = 1;
            console.log(state);
            /*show stuff here*/
        }
        else {
/*              alert("bar"); */
            var state = 0;
            console.log(state);
            /*hide stuff here*/
        }

    });
```

Comment: use toggle or toggleClass on one button no need multiple button

Comment: Googling your question's keywords might help. Lots of answers.

Comment: this line 5: `var state = 1;` causes it to always go into "else"

Comment: @Pierre In this specific case I do want to have multiple buttons doing the same thing, that's the whole idea – and both buttons must perform the same function no matter order of use.

Comment: @Lenny, try my answer now.

Comment: In if statement why are you assigning state = 0?

Comment: This is the real problem :` if(state = 0)` instead of `if(state == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line 5: var state = 1; causes it to always go into "else

```
var state = 1; //placed on global scope
 $('.boxbtn').on('click', function () {
        var boxwidth = $('.box').width();
        console.log(boxwidth);
        console.log('-'+boxwidth+'px');
        //var state = 1; removed from function scope

        if(state == 0) {
/*              alert("foo"); */
            state = 1;
            console.log(state);
            /*show stuff here*/
        }
        else {
/*              alert("bar"); */
            state = 0;
            console.log(state);
            /*hide stuff here*/
        }

    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ubk5c0f/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't work either?

Comment: try it again, had small issue that oliver found as well

Comment: Still only run the else for me

Comment: Indeed I had, your updated solution works flawlessly. Cheers mate, you just saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 0):

Declare **state** variable outside click function.

```
var state = 1; // Do not write inside click function scope
```

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the state of your object, you should use the object properties (instead of a parallel `state` variable).

Using the value of `boxwidth` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In more simple way:

```js
$('.boxbtn').on('click', function () {
    var boxwidth = $('.box').width(); //Not sure why you want this
    console.log(boxwidth);
    console.log('-'+boxwidth+'px');
    var btnVal=$(this).text(); //get the button text
    if(btnVal=="Show Stuff") //if it is show stuff
    {
        $(this).text('Hide Stuff'); //change its text
        alert('stuff shown');
        /*show stuff here*/ //do the functionality
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('Show Stuff'); //change back to normal
        alert('stuff hidden');
        /*hide stuff here*/ //hide functionality
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="boxbtn">Show Stuff</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var state = 0; //placed on global scope

$('.boxbtn').on('click', function () {
    var boxwidth = $('.box').width();
    console.log(boxwidth);
    console.log('-'+boxwidth+'px');

    if(state == 0) {
        state=1;
        console.log(state);
    }
    else {
        state = 0;
        console.log(state);
    }

});
```

Comment: changed this line  if(state == 0)

Comment: @saar please check your answer before posting. as i noticed Guruprasad Rao answer is the most suitable answer for this. using global variables are not recommended. but as a quick fix this is ok.

Comment: its just a matter of time. you had 15 mins to change your answer. finally this is not something about getting points. this is something about resolving some persons headache.